# Disable shipping method by time range

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

how can I set a time range to disable a shipping method?. The following code helps but I need to set a time to show the shipping method again:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_shipping_method_based_on_day_of_the_week_and_time', 10, 2 );
function hide_shipping_method_based_on_day_of_the_week_and_time( $rates, $package ) {
    // Establece aquí la zona horaria por defecto (http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');
    
    // Establece aquí los ID de las tarifas de envío
    $shipping_rate_ids = array( 
        'advanced_flat_rate_shipping:12945',
        'advanced_flat_rate_shipping:12947',
        'advanced_flat_rate_shipping:12956',
        'advanced_flat_rate_shipping:12959',
    );

    foreach ( $shipping_rate_ids as $shipping_rate_id ) {
        // Si el ID de la tarifa de envío está en el array anterior... 
        if ( array_key_exists( $shipping_rate_id, $rates ) 
        // ...y son más de las 3:00 pm (15:00) o es fin de semana...
        && ( ( date( 'H' ) >= 15 || in_array( date( 'N' ), [ 6, 7 ] ) ) ) ) {
            // ...se desactiva la tarifa de envío.
            unset( $rates[$shipping_rate_id] );
        }
    }
    
    return $rates;
}
```

For example, I need to reset the shipping method to 7 pm Monday to Friday

Comment: you want to hide all shipping and for all day except saturaday sunday?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show the shipping method from 7 pm Monday to Friday and hide it at other times, you need to adjust your code to reflect this logic. Here's an updated version of your code:

```
 add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'disable_shipping_method_based_on_day_and_time', 10, 2 );

function disable_shipping_method_based_on_day_and_time( $rates, $package ) {
    // Set the default timezone (http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)
    date_default_timezone_set( 'Europe/Madrid' );

    // Set the shipping rate IDs
    $shipping_rate_ids = array( 
        'advanced_flat_rate_shipping:12945',
        'advanced_flat_rate_shipping:12947',
        'advanced_flat_rate_shipping:12956',
        'advanced_flat_rate_shipping:12959',
    );

    foreach ( $shipping_rate_ids as $shipping_rate_id ) {
        // If the shipping rate ID is in the array and it is Monday to Friday and (before 3:00 pm or after 7:00 pm)...
        if ( array_key_exists( $shipping_rate_id, $rates ) 
            && ( date( 'N' ) >= 1 && date( 'N' ) <= 5 ) // Monday to Friday
            && ( date( 'H' ) < 15 || date( 'H' ) >= 19 ) ) { // Before 3:00 pm or after 7:00 pm
            // Enable the shipping method.
            continue;
        } 
        // If it is Saturday or Sunday...
        elseif ( array_key_exists( $shipping_rate_id, $rates ) 
            && ( date( 'N' ) == 6 || date( 'N' ) == 7 ) ) { // Saturday or Sunday
            // Disable the shipping method.
            unset( $rates[$shipping_rate_id] );
        }
    }

    return $rates;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe I don't explain myself well, what I want is to disable the shipping method from 3 pm to 7 pm, and on weekends

Comment: Ok, I change the code disabling the shipping method from 3 pm to 7 pm and on weekends

Comment: @Carl Above code will do the work

Comment: Well I'm testing the code, but I don't see any changes, here it is after 3 in the afternoon and the shipping method is still shown

Comment: As I see its working properly for me.

Comment: Did you check store timezone?

Comment: https://github.com/sevenbit-vasim/shipping-hours-manager.git Here I am working you can check this plugin

Comment: Yes, I have checked the store time zone, I have seen your plugin, it looks good, I may use it, thanks